# php array function without a right operator assignment?

Tags: php, arrays

I saw this in a php script about reading a csv file:

```
 array($mydata);
```

What does it make? An array from $mydata?

Comment: In addition to the answer provided below, when in doubt, look at the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it creates an array where `$mydata` is the first element. You can even put many elements in there at once:

```
php > $x = array(1,2,3);
php > var_dump($x);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

However, if that was all that happened on that line, I'd say nothing happens at all. `array()` behaves like a function that returns a new array, if it wasn't assigned to anything it was simply discarded and nothing happened. Example:

```
php > $y = 'foo';
php > array($y);
php > var_dump($y);
string(3) "foo"
```

Comment: @Chiyou Just added a bit about that. Then nothing happens at all there really.